# Using $expand=schools on Microsoft Graph educationClass members return nothing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I'm trying to retrive all schools a student belongs to from the class endpoint:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/classes/{classId}/members?$expand=schools&$select=userPrincipalName,student,schools`

The property schools are displayed on the response but it is always empty:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.educationUser)",
  "value": [
    {
      "userPrincipalName": "some@mail",
      "student": {
        "grade": "XXXXXXX",
        "studentNumber": "XXXXXX"
      },
      "schools": []
    },
    {
      "userPrincipalName": "some@mail",
      "student": {
        "grade": "XXXXXXX",
        "studentNumber": "XXXXXX"
      },
      "schools": []
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:
I confirm that the `schools` property is always empty for me. Even the education user endpoint is not working anymore:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/users/{userId}?$expand=schools&$select=userPrincipalName,student,schools`.

Here the error I get:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#education/users(userPrincipalName,student,schools,schools())/$entity",
  "userPrincipalName": "some@mail",
  "student": {
      "externalId": "XXXXXXX",
      "grade": "XXXX",
      "studentNumber": "XXXXX"
  }{
      "error": {
          "code": "InternalServerError",
          "message": "The entity instance value of type 'microsoft.graph.educationUser' doesn't have a value for property 'id'. To compute an entity's metadata, its key and concurrency-token property values must be provided.",
          "innerError": {
              "date": "2020-09-17T07:54:02",
              "request-id": "d60fc284-e410-4e39-a2db-52cb1da5f0bf",
              "client-request-id": "d60fc284-e410-4e39-a2db-52cb1da5f0bf"
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior (i.e. your query works for me). Are you sure both the Classes and their members are assigned to a School? For reference, Class, Student, and School are equatable to Group, User, and Administrative Unit.

Comment: I'm aware that Class, Student, and School are equatable to Group, User, and Administrative Unit. What is the extension name of schools property on the groups endpoint?

Comment: There isn't one. A Class is associated with a School when the underlying Group is added to the underlying Administrative Unit.

Comment: What do you get for results if you drop the $select param?

Comment: I have all user's properties but _schools_ is always empty on both endpoints

Comment: Are you sure they've been added to a school?

Answer (score 0):

In order to leverage both `$expand` and `$select`, you need to include the `id`. This provides the key-value required for Graph to connect the dots between the two.

For example, this query will fail:

```
/beta/education/users/{id}?$expand=schools&$select=userPrincipalName,student,schools
```

But by adding `id` to the select parameter, it will return the expected result:

```
/beta/education/users/{id}?$expand=schools&$select=id,userPrincipalName,student,schools
```